# How do I parse this XML in jQuery that store values in attributes only?

Tags: jquery, xml, xml-parsing

I have this XML called via $.post() and this is the return value:

```
<processResponse xmlns:client="http://xmlns...." xmlns="http://xmlns..." xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <ns2:ProcessResult xmlns:ns2="http://xmlns...">
      <ns2:StatusCode>SUCCESS</ns2:StatusCode>
      <ns2:StatusMessages>
         <ns2:StatusMessage>
            <ns2:Code>0</ns2:Code>
            <ns2:Message>Success</ns2:Message>
         </ns2:StatusMessage>
      </ns2:StatusMessages>
   </ns2:ProcessResult>
   <premises>
      <ns3:cwsPremise xmlns:ns3="http://xmlns..">
         <ns3:cwsPremiseService>
            <ns3:cwsPremiseHeader PremiseID="5855654654"/>
            <ns3:cwsPremiseDetails PremiseID="5855654654" PremiseType="BBBB" Address="3892 A street" City="PA" Postal="96456" PremiseDataArea="PB" PremiseInfo="b55" District="a333" IsMultiple="N" AllowSelfService="Y" NeedAppointment="N"/>
         </ns3:cwsPremiseService>
      </ns3:cwsPremise>
      <ns3:cwsPremise xmlns:ns3="http://xmlns...">
         <ns3:cwsPremiseService>
            <ns3:cwsPremiseHeader PremiseID="99565423587"/>
            <ns3:cwsPremiseDetails PremiseID="99565423587" PremiseType="AAAA" Address="123 Main street" City="SC" Postal="98652" PremiseDataArea="AE" PremiseInfo="K876" District="b999" IsMultiple="N" AllowSelfService="Y" NeedAppointment="N"/>
         </ns3:cwsPremiseService>
      </ns3:cwsPremise>
   </premises>
</processResponse>
```

How do parse the attributes such as PremiseID, PremiseType, Address, Postal, PremiseDataArea, PremiseInfo, District that is in `<ns3:cwsPremiseDetails PremiseID="5855654654" PremiseType="BBBB" Address="3892 A street" City="PA" Postal="96456" PremiseDataArea="PB" PremiseInfo="b55" District="a333" IsMultiple="N" AllowSelfService="Y" NeedAppointment="N"/>`?

This is my attempt:

```
$.post(url, function(xml) {

   var $PremiseID = $(xml).find('cwsPremiseDetails').attr('PremiseID').text();

   console.log($PremiseID);
   // output: nothing

});
```

Comment: Check your console for errors, also `attr()` returns a string.

Comment: Good catch, but it returns undefined.

Answer (score 0):

JQuery::attr() returns a string, not a jQuery object. Try it without the .text() call.

```
var $PremiseID = $(xml).find('cwsPremiseDetails').attr('PremiseID');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try parsing the xml first, if you don't specify the dataType as xml it won't return an XMLDocument but just a string

```
$.post(url, function(xml) {    
   var $PremiseID = $($.parseXML(xml)).find('cwsPremiseDetails').attr('PremiseID');    
   console.log($PremiseID);    
});
```